# How to download A LOT of files from S3 using the transfer utility?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have several thousand images I want to download from a S3 bucket to an iOS App.
But I'm getting memory issues I'm unable to track down.

Here is my sketchy code:

```
let client = HttpClient<[SomeImage]>()

        client.get(fromURL: URL(string: endpoint)!) {
            (result, error) in

            if let error = error {
                self.log(message: "\(error)", level: .error)
                return
            }

            if let result = result {

                let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()

                var count = 0

// just assembling a list of s3 keys to download here...
                for item in result {
                    for image in (item.images ?? []) {
                        let prefix = "\(image.key)/"
                        for key in ["\(globalGetThumbnailS3Key(byImageKey: image.key))",
                            "\(globalGetPreviewS3Key(byImageKey: image.key))"] {
                                count = count + 1

                                let completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock = {
                                    (task, URL, data, error) in

                                    if let error = error {
                                        self.log(message: "\(error)", level: .error)
                                        return
                                    }

                                    if let data = data, let localDir = FileManager.default.applicationSupportURL {
                                        do {
                                            let imageURL = localDir.appendingPathComponent(key)

                                            FileManager.default.directoryExistsOrCreate(localDir.appendingPathComponent(prefix))

                                            try data.write(to: imageURL)

                                            self.log(message: "downloaded \(prefix)\(key) to \(imageURL.absoluteString)", level: .verbose)
                                        } catch let error {
                                            self.log(message: "\(error)", level: .error)
                                            return
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                bgSyncQueue.async(group: downloadGroup) {
                                    self.transferUtility.downloadData(fromBucket: "\(globalDerivedImagesBucket)", key: key,
                                                                                expression: nil,
                                                                                completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                                                                                    (task) in

                                                                                    if let error = task.error {
                                                                                        // iirc, this error is caused, if the task couldnt be created due to being offline
                                                                                        self.log(message: "\(error)", level: .error)
                                                                                        return nil
                                                                                    }

                                                                                    if let result = task.result {
                                                                                        // do something with the task?
                                                                                        return nil

                                                                                    }

                                                                                    return nil
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }

                self.log(message: "\(count) images to download...", level: .debug)
                bgSyncQueue.activate()
                downloadGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
                    self.log(message: "All items downloaded?!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So I put all calls to the transfer utility in a serial dispatch queue, which is initially inactive. Then I activate the queue and downloading starts just fine. But after a while the app crashes with "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue."
The app is only consuming about 100M of memory though. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Putting these on a serial queue isn't doing what you think. `downloadData` is already asynchronous. So I would expect all of these to kick off in parallel, still. If you want to serialize them, you need each transfer to start the next one. As written, I would expect a lot of images to come in at the same time, and that may be overwhelming memory.

Comment: Rather than downloading files into memory and then writing them to files, I recommend using `downloadToURL:bucket:key:expression:completionHandler:` which will let you download the data directly to a file. This should dramatically improve memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I try both of your suggestions then. I'm not getting memory peaks though. Memory usage is just increasing in very small amounts and currently not going over 100megs before it crashes, so I'm suspecting that it is not memory usage, but something related, maybe because of too many simultaneous tasks. Ideally, I would be able to have a certain amount of downloads in parallel. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Rob's suggestion to use the "downloadToUrl" method was the way to go, without using GCD on my part. Thanks again, Rob!

The transferUtility seems to be a fine tool, though very badly documented.

Here is the simple code used to download about 20k of images:

```
for key in keys {
                    let imageURL = localDir.appendingPathComponent(key.1)


                    let completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock = {
                        (task, URL, data, error) in

                        if let error = error {
                            self.log(message: "failed downloading \(key.1): \(error)", level: .error)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                countingDown()
                            }

                            return
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            countingDown()
                            if let onProgress = self.onProgress {
                                onProgress(100.0 - ((100.0 / Double(total)) * Double(count)))
                            }
                        }

                        //self.log(message: "downloaded \(key.1)")
                    }

                    transferUtility.download(to: imageURL, bucket: "\(globalDerivedImagesBucket)", key: key.1, expression: nil, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith {
                        (task) in

                        if let error = error {
                            self.log(message: "\(error)", level: .error)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                countingDown()
                            }

                            return nil
                        }

                        return nil
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to consider using an `autoreleasepool` to better manage the memory used by the bridged data types as [detailed here](https://medium.com/swift2go/autoreleasepool-uses-in-2019-swift-9e8fd7b1cd3f)

Exert from article (in case of link changes)

Consider the code:

```
func run() {
    guard let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bigImage", ofType: "png") else {
        return
    }
    for i in 0..<1000000 {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
        let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    }
}
```

> Even though we’re in Swift, this will result in the same absurd memory spike shown in the Obj-C example! This is because the Data init is a bridge to the original Obj-C [NSDatadataWithContentsOfURL] -- which unfortunately still calls autorelease somewhere inside of it. Just like in Obj-C, you can solve this with the Swift version of @autoreleasepool; autoreleasepool without the @:

```
autoreleasepool {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
    let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I am no expert in Swift or Objective-C advanced memory management but I have used this in a similar scenario with good results.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to wrap in this, but i try a bit and report back :). Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: you could also look at using a NSOperationQueue to queue up all of the files to download and then setting the max concurrent operations... https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue